# How to filter latest 10 days from the current date in Views

Tags: views

I have created a listing page for News in Views. I wish to filter the news, just to show the latest 10 days from the current date. I wonder how to achieve this through Views.

Comment: have you tried to configure a filter criteria: Content: post date and there set the operator e.g: "less than" and value type : An offset from the current time such as "+1 day" or "-2 hours -30 minutes" ???

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set it using filter criteria. Look at the snapshot below.[image]

Look at the Pist date (> -10 days),by adding the field **post date** in the filter criteria and setting to -10 days will give you the nodes created in last 10 days